# ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 1:0

Tags: npm, laravel-7

Estoy en Laravel 7.

Realice los siguientes pasos:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Resultado:

> Bootstrap scaffolding installed successfully.
> Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.

Posteriormente ejecute:

```
php artisan ui vue
```

El resultado obtenido es:

> Vue scaffolding installed successfully.
> Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.

Luego ejecuté

```
npm install
```

Y después:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

El resultado fué:

> found 0 vulnerabilities

Finalmente ejecuto:

```
npm run dev
```

Y sale este error que no puedo resolver:

> ```
> ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
> |     <div class="container">
> |         <div class="row justify-content-center">
>
> webpack compiled with 1 error
> ```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score -1):

En el archivo webpack.mix.js

Agrega la siguiente propiedad `.vue({version: 2,extractVueStyles: true})`

Debe quedar algo así:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue({version: 2,extractVueStyles: true})
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

Comment: Gracias!! ;) ...